# Which optic mods fit a T821 SMG?

Tags: the-division

I have a Black Market T821 sub-machine gun and I cannot seem to find, or craft any optic mods for it.

The picture says that it takes a small optic mod, but even when I have small optic mods in my inventory I cannot seem to be able to fit them.

Does this weapon require some special type of optic mod?

[image: Black Market T821]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually stumbled across an optic mod which does fit this weapon!

[image: PRO red dot sight]